# Optimal estimation of a single parameter given data at different scales

Tags: estimation, random-variable

Let $A,B,C,D$ be independent normal random variables distributed according to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $E = A+B+C+D$.

The goal is to provide an optimal estimate of $\sigma^2$ given samples of $A,B,E$ but not $C,D$.

In this case optimal refers to minimising the root-mean square deviation of the estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2$:

$$RMSD(\hat{\sigma}^2) = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\sigma}^2-\sigma^2\right)^2\right]}$$

I can think of a simple approach to estimate $\sigma^2$ given samples of $A,B$ which is to simply compute the sample variance. Also I know that the variance of $E$ is $4\sigma^2$ so I could compute the sample variance of $E$ and divide it by 4 to get an estimate of $\sigma^2$. However it should be possible to combine the information from both $E$ and $A,B$ to improve estimation $\sigma^2$. Could you outline the approach to use both sets of information?

Comment: You didn't tell us if A,B,C,D are independent..  The variance you give for E is correct if you are assuming independence.

Comment: Have you looked at the likelihood?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Yes I intend them to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the $C+D \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2\sigma^2)$ and we don't get information about C and D individually we'll define a random variable $T=C+D$.
Then 
$P(A,B,T,E|\sigma) = N(A|0,\sigma^2)N(B|0,\sigma^2)N(A|0,\sigma^2)N(T|0,2\sigma^2)\delta(E-A-B-T)$, where $\delta()$ is a delta function, N(.|..) is the PDF of the Normal distribution. Therefore the likelihood of A,B,E is

$$P(A,B,E|\sigma) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}2\sigma^3}\exp\left(-\frac{A^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{B^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{(E-A-B)^2}{4\sigma^2}\right)$$

From this, one can derive the maximum likelihood estimator for $\sigma^2$
which will be:
$$\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{3\,N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N}\left(A_i^2+B_i^2+\frac{1}{2}(E_i-A_i-B_i)^2\right)$$ $N$ here is the number of samples.
This estimator is unbiased and because it is ML it is also a minimum variance estimator.

Comment: Could you explain your notation?

Comment: I thought that I don't use anything non-standard with the exception of maybe of the delta-function.

Comment: Testing in Matlab reveals this is a superior estimator to both of my naive approaches. I believe $N$ is the number of samples of $A, B$ or $E$.

Comment: I've added to the post that N is indeed the number of samples.

Comment: This estimator is *biased*, not unbiased.  Also, you seem implicitly to assume the samples are independent, but it's not evident whether they are or are not.

Comment: The author commented below the post that "Yes I intend them to be independent. "

Comment: I intend A,B,C,D to be independent. However E is dependent on the value of A.