# Optimal estimation of a single parameter given data at different scales 2

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, estimation, error

This is a follow up question to my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250772/optimal-estimation-of-a-single-parameter-given-data-at-different-scales#250777)

Let $A,B,C$ be independent normally distribution variables $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ with unknown variance $\sigma^2$. Let $D = A + B + C$.

Given $n$ samples of $A$ and $D$ suggest an estimator $\hat{\sigma}_D^2$ the variance of $D$. Obviously a simple approach is to simple compute the sample variance of $D$. However can the extra information provided by the samples of $A$ be used to reduce the error of the estimate $\hat{\sigma}_D^2$? let the error be defined by the root-mean-square deviation:

\begin{equation}
RMSD\left(\hat{\sigma}_D^2\right) = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\sigma}_D^2-\sigma_D^2\right)^2\right]}
\end{equation}

My approach:

$$D \sim \mathcal{N}(0,3\sigma^2)$$

Compute sample variance of $D$ notated $\text{Var}(D)$ and sample variance of $A$ notated $\text{Var}(A)$:

$$\hat{\sigma}_D^2 = 3\lambda_1\text{Var}(A) + \lambda_2\text{Var}(D)$$

Arbitrarily take $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0.5$. However there is no reason to think this is optimal. Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have independent samples of $A$ and $D$ or one sample of their joint distribution $(A,D)$?  BTW, this appears to be identical to your previous question.

Comment: @whuber One sample of their joint distribution $(A,D)$. I don't believe this is the same question since the goal is to predict $\sigma^2_D$ and not $\sigma^2$. Perhaps my understand is not good enough to realise this is fundamentally the same problem.

Comment: Since you have explicitly assumed $\sigma_D^2=\sigma^2$, I cannot see any distinction.